# Error when trying to run on device

Tags: nativescript

When trying to run

```
tns run android --device xxxx
```

I always get an err like this:

```
Error: error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
could not read ok from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon

at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Raziff\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\common\mobile\mobile-core\android-device-discovery.js:54:25)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
at Pipe.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

Any way to fix this. I've tried it with various devices.

Comment: I got the same error and it turned out that my PATH variable wasn't set properly to point android-sdk. Try it out.

Comment: I think there is a bug in the android itself  checkout the below link [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204328)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your port? Your port which is 5037 probably is being used by other application. You can check your port using Windows Task Manager.

Comment: the only thing using port 5037 is adb. which is what it's trying to use anyway

Answer (score 0):

When you run tns more than 2 times It sometimes consumes your port, the thing you need to do is to run

```
netstat -a -o -n
```

You will get the list of tasks running on your machine.
You need to look for the 5037 port in the local address column, after you find it, check the process ID (PID) of the task.
Then kill it with

```
taskkill /f /pid 123456
```

Now you can continue with developement :)

Answer (score 0):

What I discovered was there was a difference in ADB versions being used throughout the system. Here is the command I used to find them:

```
where /r C:\ adb.exe
```

This produced the results:

```
C:\Program Files\Expo XDE\resources\app\node_modules\xdl\binaries\windows\adb\adb.exe
C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools\adb.exe
C:\Users\kyle\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
C:\Users\kyle\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb backup\adb.exe
```

Navigating to each directory and running:

```
adb.exe version
```

Allowed me to see that Expo was running ADB version:

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
Revision fd9e4d07b0f5-android
```

While Genymotion using the custom SDK had version (c:\Users\kyle\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe):

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Revision 3db08f2c6889-android
```

As a test I took the adb files (adb.exe, AdbWinApi.dll, AdbWinUsbApi.dll) from

```
c:\Users\kyle\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
```

and placed them into a backup folder. I then moved the adb files located at

```
c:\Program Files\Expo XDE\resources\app\node_modules\xdl\binaries\windows\adb\adb.exe
```

into that same location. I killed adb with:

```
adb kill-server
```

which caused a restart of the adb server automatically due to having my Genymotion device already running. I hit the "Restart" button inside of the Expo XDE and it immediately began working. Here is the log where I hit the restart button at 1:13:04 AM:

simply all adb.exe files must have same versions.